# How to set type of jsonPayload in BigQuery logging sink?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-logging

I have created a Google Cloud Logging sink to BigQuery. When a log is first sent to the sink, a schema for the BQ table is generated as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/bigquery). So for example if I log JSON like this:

```
{
  "foo": "bar",
  "baz": 10
}
```

Then a schema like this (omitting much) is created:

```
jsonPayload RECORD
  foo STRING
  baz FLOAT
```

What I would like though is a schema like this:

```
jsonPayload JSON
```

because I would also like to have log messages with different jsonPayloads (different and currently unknown keys) in the same table.

I tried to change what I am logging to look like this thinking it might not parse the jsonPayload into a schema but it did not work.

```
{
  "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.protobuf.Struct",
  "foo": "bar",
  "baz": 10
}
```

It didn't treat the `@type` field specially as [I hoped it might](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/bigquery#type-specifier) but rather just renamed `@type` to `_type` and gave it the `STRING` type.

Comment: Perhaps I should define the table schema explicitly before the first log comes in setting the jsonPayload type to JSON?

Comment: I tried predefining the table schema with jsonPayload being a JSON type but then got export errors saying "This field: jsonpayload is not a record."

Comment: I guess I can log the json as text and then treat it as json in queries.